# Backbone: Correct way of passing 'this' reference to anon functions in success/error callbacks

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Given the backbone view function below, what is the correct way of passing `this` (i.e. the current view) to the anonymous function defined in the callbacks?

```
addSomething: function(e) {
    var newSomething= this.model.somethings.create({
        someProperty: xxx
    }, {
        success: function(m, response) {
            this.doSomething(); //***HERE****
        },
        error: function(m, response) {
            //Error
        }
    });
},
```

Without and changes, the `this` in the anon function is set to the window.

I can a set a reference like this:

```
var thisView = this;
```

and then just refer to `thisView` instead of `this` in the anon function, but this doesn't seem very elegant.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to better organize my code and work around this problem, I never put success and error callbacks directly in-line with my calls. I always split them out to their own functions. This let's me keep the code clean and also use the `_.bindAll` method to ensure I have the correct context for `this`.

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "createSuccess", "createError");
  },

  addSomething: function(e) {
    var newSomething= this.model.somethings.create({someProperty: xxx}, {
      success: this.createSuccess,
      error: this.createError
    });
  },

  createSuccess: function(m, response) {
    this.doSomething();
  },

  createError: function(m, response) {
    //Error
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems like a nice tidy approach.  I'm a little concerned about how many functions I'm going to get in my views, but I think it's a good compromise.

Comment: yeah, it's all trade-offs, really. jumbled code with lots of nested functions vs lots of functions. i prefer lots of separate functions as it's just easier to read. :)

Comment: I agree with @DerickBailey.  I wouldn't call it a trade-off.  It is about writing readable and maintainable code.  If you have too many functions in your view that it is a problem, then you are probably doing too much in your view and you should break it up more.

Comment: @BrianGenisio Well I think readability is a rather subjective topic.  How do you propose I break up the view object?

Comment: @UpTheCreek: Although readability might be subjective at the individual level, we know that there are things you can do to make things more objectively readable... in other words, studies have found... etc etc.  Anyways, When I suggest that you break things up, I am coming from a "Separations of Concerns" perspective.  Lots of methods on a class are a "code smell" and often indicate that a class is doing too much.  When that happens, you need to ask "what are the things that this class does".  If it is more than one thing, break it up along those lines.

Comment: I believe this also avoids memory leaks, doesn't it? I'm still trying to wrap my brain around that though... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
this.doSomething.call(this);
```

Or send whatever you want `this` to be in `doSomething`

Comment: Interesting - have not used call before.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `that` convention:

```
addSomething: function(e) {

var that = this;

var newSomething= this.model.somethings.create({
        someProperty: xxx
    }, {
        success: function(m, response) {
            that.doSomething(); //***THAT HERE****
        },
        error: function(m, response) {
            //Error
        }
    });
}
```

This is quite a common pattern in javascript especially when context is lost with nested functions. Nested functions do have access to the variables in the outer function and hence it works.

Derick's approach makes the code cleaner, irrespective of the fact of having extra functions but if you don't want them use 'that' ;)

Comment: This has been my approach so far.

Comment: I actually believe this approach is better than the adopted answer, as the programmers do not need to hard code all the methods they want to bind.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone has a builtin way to handle this: the 'context' attribute.

```
this.model.destroy({
    success: function (model, resp, options) {
        model.releaseLock();
        window.location.href = this.getURLForModelID(model.get('id'));
    },
    error: function (model, resp, options) {
        this.displayError(resp.message);
    },
    context: this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context seemingly without using `call`, `bind` or `apply` (or Lo-Dash) by creating an anonymous function, passing `this`, and then immediately calling the handler methods on the object's prototype as shown in the following CoffeeScript example:

```
View = require('views/base/view')

module.exports = class LoginPageView extends View
  template: require('./templates/login-page')
  events:
    'submit form': '_doLogin'

  # Called when the template is bound using Chaplin
  attach: ->
    super
    @$loginButton = @$('[name="login"]')

  _doLogin: (evt) ->
    evt.preventDefault()
    @$loginButton.attr 'disabled', true
    email = @$('[name="email"]').val()
    password = @$('[name="password"]').val()
    @model.save {email, password},
      success: (model, response, options) =>
        @_loginSuccess model, response, options
      error: (model, response, options) =>
        @_loginError model, response, options

  _loginSuccess: (model, response, options) ->
    # TODO: Implement method body

  _loginError: (model, response, options) ->
    # TODO: Implement method body
```

Perhaps it's a little verbose with the argument names, and the extra closure created by the anonymous function isn't the best implementation performance-wise, but it's certainly a bit easier to grasp and manage when working with individuals of varied skill levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [$.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```js
        success: $.proxy(function(m, response) {
            this.doSomething(); 
        }, this),
        error: function(m, response) {
            //Error
        }
```